# Google Maps not loading when it is loaded second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I called google map into a bootstrap panel. The map loads fine first time and in the second time it does not load. I tried resizing the map and many other solutions but it did not work.

I used the following files 1.Bootstrap JS 2.Bootstrap css and 3.Jquery JS and UI

The following is the code

```js
var NirMap = document.getElementById('placeMap');

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
  
  var map = new GMap2(NirMap);
  
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(_lat, _long), 17);
  map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  
}

var mapOptions = {
  
  center: new google.maps.LatLng( _lat, _long),
  zoom: 17,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  
};

map = new google.maps.Map(NirMap, mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can check the problem at my site given below for more analysis
[nirvanamrutam.com](http://nirvanamrutam.com)

Comment: Did you notice the "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" in your browser console?

Comment: GBrowserIsCompatible, GLatLng etc looks like Google Maps API v2, which hasn't been available for a long time.  This code should be rewritten to API v3 (which you're doing in the rest of the code you've posted).  See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps API has nothing to do with reloading for the second time. I've made a quick snippet which demonstrates the functionality, which clicked the "Zoom" button reloads the maps with random zoom. However, for every reload you need to make a new map object. [View demo in JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/doyujeyimo/edit?html,output)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    button {
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button onclick="initMap()">Zoom</button>
    <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -34.397,
                lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: Math.floor(Math.random(10) * 10)
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```